# Getting the column names/alias from query using ODBC PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I'm building a custom query writer for my team where they can simply put in a query and it will export it to a csv file.  It is using the ODBC PDO driver.  How can I extract out the column name/alias?  A query would typically have something like this:

```
$query = "SELECT
jcst.Loc_No,
jcst.Emp_No,
round(Sum(jcst.Amt_1), 2) AS Gross_Wages,
round(Sum(jcst.Amt_12),2) as Local_Tax,
round(sum(jcst.Amt_3+jcst.Amt_2),2) As Fica,
round(sum(jcst.Amt_4),2) as FUTA,
round(Sum(jcst.Amt_5),2) as SUTA,
round(sum(jcst.Amt_10),2) as Admin_Fee,
round(Sum(jcst.Amt_13),2) as Other_Costs
FROM Master";
```

I would need Loc_No, Emp_No, Gross_Wages, Local_Tax, FICA, SUTA, Admin_Fee, Other_Costs as the header column information.  How can I get the column/ alias names out based on a query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($sth->fetch() as $key => $value) {
    $array[] = $key;
}

var_dump($array);
```

For those who are wondering how to do it!

Answer (score -1):

you may try if you are expecting the display as below

```
$result = mysqli_fetch_array(....);
...
foreach ($result as $res)
{
echo $res['Loc_No']."<br \>";
echo $res['Emp_No']."<br \>";
echo $res['Gross_Wages']."<br \>";
echo $res['Local_Tax']."<br \>";
echo $res['FICA']."<br \>";
echo $res['SUTA']."<br \>";
echo $res['Admin_Fee']."<br \>";
echo $res['Other_Costs']."<br \>";
}
....
```